# How to reverse a linked list in pairs

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I want to reverse a linked list in pair such that if the list is 1->2->3->4->X
then it should output the following 2->1->4->3->X

I have tried to solve this problem but it doesn't seem to run. Guys, can you please help me with what is wrong in my code.

```
ListNode* reverseListInPairs(ListNode *head){
        ListNode *current = head,*newHead = NULL,*temp = NULL,*prev = NULL;
        while(current != NULL && current->next != NULL){

            temp = current->next;
            current->next = current->next->next;
            temp->next = current;
            prev->next = temp;
            prev = current;
            current = current->next;
            if(newHead == NULL){
                newHead = temp;
            }
        }
        return newHead;
    }
```

Comment: Intially `prev` is NULL, so reaching Null->next leads to error

Comment: Also handle cases like what If there is only one Node then your newHead returns null.
Take more examples and put them on paper

Comment: Hey @tnxy, try out what I have commented and see the link that was provided.  Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is wrong in my code.

The main problem I see is here:

> ```
>             prev->next = temp;
> ```

On the first iteration of the loop, `prev` is still `NULL` at that point, so you're performing a null-pointer dereference.

You can resolve that issue and also remove the special case for the list head by introducing a synthetic head node in front of the real nodes:

```
ListNode* reverseListInPairs(ListNode *head) {
    ListNode fake_head = { .next = head };
    ListNode *prev = &fake_head;
    ListNode *current = head;

    while (current != NULL && current->next != NULL) {
        ListNode *temp = current->next;

        current->next = current->next->next;
        temp->next = current;
        prev->next = temp;

        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    return fake_head.next;
}
```

I've stuck as close as possible to your original code there, but personally, I'd tighten it up a little further.  In particular, you don't need to maintain both `current` and `prev` across iterations; just the latter would be sufficient.

```
ListNode* reverseListInPairs(ListNode *head) {
    ListNode fake_head = { .next = head };
    ListNode *prev = &fake_head;

    while (prev->next && prev->next->next) {
        ListNode *first = prev->next;
        ListNode *second = first->next;

        prev->next = second;
        first->next = second->next;
        second->next = first;

        prev = first;
    }

    return fake_head.next;
}
```

Comment: ListNode fake_head = { .next = head };Can you explain me this line. I am unfamiliar with the syntax

Comment: @tnxy, `ListNode fake_head` declares an object of type `ListNode` (as opposed to a pointer to one).  The rest of that line specifies an *initializer* for `fake_head`.  The whole thing is analogous to `int x = 1;`.  The initializer syntax for a structure type requires bounding curly braces (`{}`), and within I have used a *designated initializer* to specify the initial value of the `next` member by name instead of by declaration order.

Answer (score 0):

```
Node *reverse (Node *head, int k)  
{  
    Node* current = head;  
    Node* next = NULL;  
    Node* prev = NULL;  
    int count = 0;  
    while (current != NULL && count < k)  
    {  
        next = current->next;  
        current->next = prev;  
        prev = current;  
        current = next;  
        count++;  
    }  
    if (next != NULL)  
    head->next = reverse(next, k);  
    return prev;  
}
```

pass the value of k is 2

Comment: This does not seem to address the actual question of what is wrong with the OP's code.

Comment: Justing posting code is not acceptable, please read guidelines before answering a question and provide some examples of why you chose this, 
Also the question asks what is the problem with a piece of code not a code that works for some K

Answer (score 0):

```
void pairWiseSwap(struct Node* head) 
{ 
    struct Node* temp = head; 

    /* Traverse further only if there are at-least two nodes left */
    while (temp != NULL && temp->next != NULL) { 
        /* Swap data of node with its next node's data */
        swap(&temp->data, &temp->next->data); 

        /* Move temp by 2 for the next pair */
        temp = temp->next->next; 
    } 
}
```

Sourced from [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pairwise-swap-elements-of-a-given-linked-list/).

As for what is the error, it has been pointed out that prev is already NULL.

```
 ListNode *current = head,*newHead = NULL,*temp = NULL,*prev = NULL;
 .
 .
 prev->next = temp;
```

We can't have NULL->next as it will throw a segmentation fault.